# How can I rotate a video?

Tags: mac, video, software

I just recorded a video on my phone, but when I play it on my Mac it's in the wrong orientation.

How can I rotate the video by 90 degrees so that I can upload it to youtube?

Free solutions are preferred.

---

I just found out how to do it using YouTube's Video Editor which has rotate left/right buttons.

But this is not an answer how to rotate on Mac.

Comment: Vertical Video Syndrome (VVS): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bt9zSfinwFA

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use MPEG Stream Clip: http://www.squared5.com/svideo/mpeg-streamclip-mac.html

Simply open the file and choose to export it from the file menu in a format of your choosing, selecting the appropriate rotation in the selection box.

You can find out the current format of the video by choosing File > Show Stream Info as to match the export to the input settings if required.

Comment: MPEG Streamclip is one of the best applications! +1 for an awesome recommendation!

Comment: It may be great but it's totally unnecessary for this task. QuickTime is fully capable of this.

Comment: Agreed if you need to do this goto the next suggestion. Do not introduce more software to complete this task. Sam's method using the built in quicktime program is far easier.

Comment: While MPEG Streamclip is an excellent program, it is very wonky when doing rotations: it's very difficult to get the settings right. By contrast, Quicktime does what you expect the first time, although almost always with a much larger file than you began with (then you can use MPEG Streamclip to get the file small again!).

Answer (score 49):

### Use QuickTime to Rotate Videos

You don't need to use any 3rd party tools to do this. It's built right in to QuickTime Player.

Any file that can be opened in QuickTime can be rotated by choosing `Edit > Rotate Left (or Right)` or by typing <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>L / R</kbd>.

If you alter a movie file in this way and attempt to close the file (<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>) you will be prompted to save your changes. Save them to a new file and you will have a newly rotated video.

### Share your Video on YouTube with QuickTime

QuickTime also has a built-in way to share your video on YouTube. With the video open (and correctly rotated now) select `Share > YouTube...`

Comment: Well this didn't work. The video when rotated goes black.

Comment: Same problem The video when rotated goes black

Comment: Same here, using QuickTime on El Capitan.

Answer (score 21):

Using `ffmpeg` you have a few techniques:

For newer versions of `ffmpeg` use:

```
ffmpeg -i in.avi -vf "transpose=1" out.avi
```

For older versions of `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -vfilters "rotate=90" -i input.mp4 output.mp4
```

---

Using `mencoder`:

```
mencoder -oac copy -ovc lavc -vf rotate=1 original.mp4 -o 90_CW_rotated.mp4 
mencoder -oac copy -ovc lavc -vf rotate=2 original.mp4 -o 90_CCW_rotated.mp4
```

Sources: [ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208522/ffmpeg-on-iphone-modifying-video-orientation), [mencoder](https://superuser.com/questions/162259/ffmpeg-rotate-mp4-90)

Comment: For further reference: use `ffmpeg -vf`

Comment: The above example is to rotate clockwise.  To rotate counter-clockwise, use `-vf "transpose=2"`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to trust a web-based solution you can do the following:

1. Go to [video.online-convert.com](http://video.online-convert.com/convert-to-avi).
2. From left menu, choose what is your desired file format (select avi or mp4 if you don’t know much about this)
3. Choose your file, it can be of any size and format
4. Without changing or entering any settings, just choose to which angle you want to rotate your video
5. Press “Convert button” and wait for the file to upload and convert.
6. Converted file will be automatically downloaded

[Source](http://howbees.com/2013/08/28/how-to-rotate-or-flip-a-video-online-best-way-any-file-size/)

Comment: Answers should be more than just a link, can you please summarize the video in your answer?

Comment: Sorry, it's not a video, it's a tutorial. This tutorial is simple as compared to Wikihow's method where they tell you to download software and other complex methods that are difficult for basic users. I've edited and simplified my answer.

Comment: The idea is to make answers stand on their own. Links may break rendering link-only answers useless.

Answer (score 0):

Use the <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd>, etc. when you open the video in Quicktime.  That should do the trick.

Answer (score -2):

Just open QT and it automatically rotates it. Then simply export it.