# Rotating a video in QT player 10

Tags: iphone, quicktime, mov

I'm trying to rotate an iPhone 4S vid 90degrees Counter Clockwise.

I've seen lots of posts and [answers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6297/how-can-i-rotate-a-video) that say there is an 'Edit > Rotate Left' option in Quicktime Player. I can't see it! I have QT Player 10.0 on Snow Leopard.

Could someone help me out? I've tried various other apps, and even though some of them have worked, none have managed to rotate it in a format that can then be synced back to the iPhone (for editing work in iMovie iOS app and Vimeo app).

Notes: I don't have iLife or QT Pro, just QT Player :/

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using QuickTime Player 10.1 on OS 10.7.3, I see this option in the Edit menu. My guess is that it appeared either in Lion or in the 10.0 > 10.1 QT update. Open Software Update and check if the QuickTime Player 10.1 update is available for Snow Leopard.

[image: Edit menu in QT 10.1]

Comment: I, too, don't have iLife or QT Pro.